# Name, Place, Animal, Thing

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, pattern

**Which famous South African's image can replace the question mark and why?**

[image]

Comment: I first thought the second person was rot13(Nxba, ohg gura V fnj gur anzr Cngevpx.... ba gur fvqr bs gur vzntr ohg fgvyy V pna'g frrz gb trg n uvg ivn vzntr frnepu.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah His name is rot13(Qba Gbk). He is not that popular I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The famous  South African should be

> **Elon Musk**

The name of the two first people

> 1. IDA Flo 
>  2. Don Tox 
>  IDA Flo is under "place" and now we switch place of the two and get Flo IDA. Add an R in between and we get Florida. 
> Same thing with Don Tox, switch place of the two and you get Tox Don. Add an O in between and you get  [Toxodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxodon) which is an extinct animal.

Now for the "thing" which is suppose to be represented by a famous South African

> my mind immediately thought of Nelson Mandela (which doesn't look promising since no word can be made by Mandela(?)Nelson but then I thought of Elon Musk. And indeed if we switch place of the two: Musk Elon we can, by adding an M in between, create the word [Muskmelon](https://www.britannica.com/plant/muskmelon) which is a "thing" (fruit)

Here is an image:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> Ah so I had the thing as: ENABLER
>
>  Switching 'ENA' and 'LER you get LERENA - the South African boxer.
>
>  Also the 'R' 'O' and 'B' added letters neatly spells the name 'ROB'.
>
>  Muskmelon is more of a thing than an enabler though! Fair play